# ActionScript 3 BitmapData's methods not implemented. How do I access its methods?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Ultimately, what I'm trying to do is apply gamma correction to some bitmaps that I load at runtime.  I was able to create a `BitmapData` object, then create a `Bitmap` from the `BitmapData`, and I was able to add the `Bitmap` to the stage with `addChild`.  So far so good.  But if I try altering the `BitmapData` in any way (either before or after creating the `Bitmap`) I get warnings like these:

```
Warning: The method BitmapData::fillRect() is not implemented
Warning: The method BitmapData::paletteMap() is not implemented
Warning: The method BitmapData::clone() is not implemented
```

To simplify things as much as possible, let's just try to run the example code at https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#paletteMap()

I create a blank ActionScript 3 document, press F9 and I copy and paste this code into the timeline, on Layer_1: Frame 1:

```
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.geom.Point;

var myBitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(80, 80, false, 0x00FF0000);
myBitmapData.fillRect(new Rectangle(20, 20, 40, 40), 0x0000FF00);

var redArray:Array = new Array(256);
var greenArray:Array = new Array(256);

for(var i:uint = 0; i < 255; i++) {
    redArray[i] = 0x00000000;
    greenArray[i] = 0x00000000;
}

redArray[0xFF] = 0x0000FF00;
greenArray[0xFF] = 0x00FF0000;

var bottomHalf:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 40);
var pt:Point = new Point(0, 0);
myBitmapData.paletteMap(myBitmapData, bottomHalf, pt, redArray, greenArray);

var bm1:Bitmap = new Bitmap(myBitmapData);
addChild(bm1);
```

That's all just copied directly from the example.  And when I try running that, the log tells me that `fillRect` and `paletteMap` are not implemented.  I've tried in Animate 19 and Flash Pro CS6 with the same results in both places.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?  Why are `BitmapData`'s methods not implemented and how do I implement them?

Comment: Ok, I copy-pasted this code sample into blank **AS3** source in my **CS6** and it just worked (there was a small red-green colored square). You should probably quote the complete error message (with its # error number). The only wild idea I have at this point is that Flash **EOL** affects the result somehow for you.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look @Organis When you told me it was working for you, I figured there must be something wrong with how I'm trying to run/test my file.  I had been using the Scaleform Launcher from inside Animate.  I downloaded the Flash Player content debugger and I test my published file with that, and everything seems to be working.  For future reference though, is there a better way to test my files and/or get the full error number?  Scaleform Launcher doesn't provide much in the way of debugging info.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the Scaleform Launcher, which I was using to test the movie.  Instead of testing with the Scaleform Launcher, go to Control > Test.  Everything seems to be working fine there.

Unfortunately, if you depend on the Scaleform integration for interacting with Flash from inside a game engine, you won't be able to modify bitmaps from inside Flash.  Scaleform seems to have left out all the code behind `bitmapData`'s methods.

And I think it's not likely that anyone will ever again need to run gamma correction on bitmaps in Flash, but just in case, here's how you do it:

```
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.geom.Point;

var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BeforeColorCorrection();

var rectangle:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmapData.width, bitmapData.height);
var point:Point = new Point(0, 0);
var redGamma:Array = new Array(256);
var greenGamma:Array = new Array(256);
var blueGamma:Array = new Array(256);
var gamma:Number = 2.0;

var corrected:Number;
var i:int

for(i = 0; i <= 255; i++)
{
    corrected = 255 * Math.pow((i / 255.0), (1.0 / gamma));

    redGamma[i] = uint(corrected) << 16;
    greenGamma[i] = uint(corrected) << 8;
    blueGamma[i] = uint(corrected);
}

bitmapData.paletteMap(bitmapData, rectangle, point, redGamma, greenGamma, blueGamma);

var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapData);

addChild(bitmap);
```

`BeforeColorCorrection` is an image in my library with "Export for ActionScript" checked.  If Scaleform worked, I would replace that image during gameplay and run a function to brighten it via gamma correction.

Comment: Maybe not in Flash (browser) but AS3 itself can still be compiled into a native app.