# as3 error 1006 removeEventListener is not a function

Tags: actionscript-3

Why do I get the 1006 error

> removeEventListener is not a function

```
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkStage);

function checkStage(e: Event): void {
    if (stage != null) {
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, repeat);
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, rt);
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkStage);
    }

}
```

Comment: In terms of **AS3** the code is valid. I checked and it works just fine, with no errors. Unless you launch it in some non-standard environment, like the problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68050093/actionscript-3-bitmapdatas-methods-not-implemented-how-do-i-access-its-methods

Comment: Is this code on a timeline? Probably for timeline code "this" is not a `EventDispatcher` descendant thus has no access to `removeEventListener()`.